# Como capturar o valor do atributo corrente com jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho o seguinte formulário em html:

```
<form>First name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    <br>Last name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="sobrenome">
</form>
```

E o código jQuery:
    $(document).ready(function () {

```
    $('input').change(function()
    {   
        alert($(this).attr('name'));
    });
});
```

Ao alterar o valor de determinado campo quero dar um alert com o nome do atributo, porém, queria fazer isso sem ter que informar a tag do seletor, ou seja, ao invés de informar o **input** quero que o mesmo seja obtido automaticamente com base no elemento que estou atualmente alterando. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 4):

`*` para todos elementos.

```
$('*')
```

Caso queira fazer uma lista de elementos separe por `,`:

```
$('input,select,textarea')
```

Você pode também usar o `filter` :

```
jQuery('*').filter(function(){
    var accept = [
        'input',
        'select',
        'textarea'
    ];
    var tag = jQuery(this).prop('nodeName');
    return jQuery.inArray(tag.toLowerCase(), accept);
});
```